Attraction, sexuality and love tags
We have two tags for attraction (2 questions) and physical-attraction (29 questions).
attraction is a newly added broader one, but so far not in use. What do we do with these tags?
Other related tags which might also be of relevance:

sexuality (48 questions)
love (11 questions)


I have asked a tag question elsewhere, but are you not the person to do something about tags? What can we humble non-mods do? I mean, I often see tags that need to be merged. Or empty tags. Superfluous tags.

I also don't see why we need a separate tag for attraction and physical attraction. It would be preferable if they were merged into the attraction tag.
